# Is there a word for this description?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word for inheritance from male to male to male. For example, a father has a son(1) and a daughter; the son(1) has sons(2); those sons(2) have sons(3). And maybe the last name is keep amongst the males, but the daughters would take the husband's surname(which would be different). In Chinese culture, this is the tradition. Is this true for other cultures?

Answer (score 2):

*Patrilineal* is another term for inheritance in the male line.

In terms of property inheritance, this is not typical in the United States, where inheritance is determined by state law.  Laws often vary.

A will determines who inherits what, or what percentage of an estate.  However, a substantial portion of an estate often goes to a man's wife.

If he dies intestate (without a will), the laws of each state determine how much goes to the widow (or spouse), the descendants, and other relatives, especially parents and brothers and sisters.    https://estate.findlaw.com/wills/what-happens-if-i-die-without-a-will-.html

Comment: @touchstone Thanks, fixed.

Comment: It's worth comparing *patriarchal* to *patrilineal*. The latter is exclusively about inheritance, while the first one can be applied to a much broader set of notions.

Comment: @PhilSweet Agree, but inheritance is broader than property, including, significantly, genetic inheritance, where traits may or may not be patrilineal.

Answer (score 0):

*Inheritance in the male line*.

It is generally true in Western culture (except for Iceland), though nowadays some women choose not to take their husband's surname.

Answer (score 0):

Does [agnatic primogeniture](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/agnatic) meet your needs? It's definitely *not* a common term, but it is used to refer to both "property inheritance goes to the first son" and "tracing lineage exclusively through the male line". See [wikipedia for the second usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primogeniture#Agnatic_primogeniture), which also goes into some of the history of primogeniture in Europe.

If not, can you provide additional context for your word request? E.g., using it in an essay, talking to other people, just wanting to understand if the concept translates...?